Mysql Is there a way to remove duplicate outputs on a query when using a CTE?
I have a CTE with 2 selects from 2 different tables. One CTE to sum the billableTargets(bt) table target billable hours and one CTE clientbillin(cb) to sum the hours(billed). All selects come from the billableTargets(bt) table and that appears to function correctly. When I add a select for hours(cb) and join the clientbillin(cb) table, it appears that for every record on the cb, it duplicates the numbers from the bt table. For every row that has billed hours for the same company on different dates, I get a new ouput for that billed time with the target shown again.
WITH
    cb AS(
        SELECT
            clientbilling.id,
            `Date`,
            `Description`,
            `Hours`,
            `Kilometers`,
            `Company`,
            `Date Created`,
            `Employee`,
            SUM(clientbilling.Hours) AS 'Billed'
        FROM
            clientbilling
        JOIN site ON clientbilling.Company = site.siteID
        JOIN users ON clientbilling.Employee = users.id
        WHERE
            MONTH(clientbilling.Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        GROUP BY
            Company,
            Employee
        ORDER BY
            Employee),
    -- second cte
    bt AS(
        SELECT
            billableTargets.id,
            billableTargets.Employee,
            billableTargets.Company,
            SUM(billableTargets.Target) AS 'Goal',
            billableTargets.Date
        FROM
            billableTargets
        WHERE
            MONTH(billableTargets.Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        GROUP BY
            Company,
            Employee)
SELECT
   bt.Company 'Company',
   bt.Employee,
    bt.Goal,
    cb.Billed,
    cb.Date
FROM
    bt
JOIN site ON bt.Company = site.siteID
JOIN users ON bt.Employee = users.id
JOIN cb ON bt.Company = cb.Company
ORDER BY Employee, Company



Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Change
JOIN cb ON bt.Company = cb.Company

to
JOIN cb ON bt.Company = cb.Company AND bt.Employee = cb.Employee

Otherwise, you're getting a cross product of all the employees in the same company.
There's also no point in selecting columns in the CTEs that you don't use in the main query. So you don't need most of the columns in the cb CTE.
The id and Date columns that you're selecting in the bt subquery are meaningless. They will be taken from arbitrary rows in each Company, Employee group. If you had ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode enabled you would have gotten an error because of this.

Thank you so much for the help. This did fix my issue. Just one additional question, could you break down / explain why the changes you made changed the out come of the query?

Suppose company 1 has employee 1 and employee 2. The join will create multiple rows: cb.Employee=1 + bt.Employee=1, cb.Employee=1 + bt.Employee=2, cb.Employee=2 + bt.Employee=1, and cb.Employee=2 + bt.Employee=2. When you don't include a column in the join, you get all combinations.

You would see this if you included cb.Employee in the SELECT list.

When you're debugging a query like this, it helps to show all the columns from the tables being joined, so you can see where the duplication comes from.
